# simple conditional mod_rewrite for redirecting wrong urls

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf, ihs

I have an assignment to add storeId parameter to wrong urls.

It should behave like this:

If url has directory`store/a` in it like `www.example.com/store/a` -  the next directory in path has to be

`www.example.com/store/a/dir1` or

`www.example.com/store/a/dir2` or

`www.example.com/store/a/dir3`

otherwise it should add storeId parameter to the end of it

for example: 
`www.example.com/store/a/dir3blahblah/something?storeId=123` or

`www.example.com/store/a/dir3blahblah?storeId=123`

I wrote a httpd.conf rewriterule here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store/a/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/a/dir1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/a/dir2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/a/dir3
RewriteRule ^/store/(.*) /store/$1?&storeId=123 [PT,L]
```

But as a newb to configuring that server I'm 80% sure that there are some mistakes and unfortunately I have no chance to test that piece. So I'm expecting that you guys might check that out and maybe help me to fix my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Is it for an homework ?

Comment: for production :D